# React store goes blank when product is selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm following a tutorial video on how to create an online store, and I'm having trouble with the code (I'm using React on VSCode). When I click on a product from the products page to see its description the browser page goes blank. The terminal shows that everything is running as it should and there are no problems with the code however the (VSCode OUTPUT) shows:
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

and the browser teminal shows:
ItemDetails.jsx:147 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice').

The last Box seems to be the problem. I've marked it out.

This seems to be the code causing the problem:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { IconButton, Box, Typography, Button, Tabs, 
Tab } from "@mui/material";
import FavoriteBorderOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons- 
material/FavoriteBorderOutlined";
import AddIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Add";
import RemoveIcon from "@mui/icons- 
material/Remove";
import { shades } from "../../theme";
import { addToCart } from "../../state";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Item from "../../components/Item";

const ItemDetails = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { itemId } = useParams();
    const { value, setValue } = 
    useState("description")
    const { count, setCount } = useState(1);
    const { item, setItem } = useState(null);
    const { items, setItems } = useState([]);

    const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
    }

    async function getItem() {
        const item = await fetch(
            `http://localhost:1337/api/items/${itemId}?populate- 
            image`,
            { method: "GET" }
        );
        const itemJson = await item.json();
        setItem(itemJson.data);
    }async function getItems() {
        const items = await fetch(
            "http://localhost:1337/api/items?populate=image",
        { method: "GET"}
    );
    const itemsJson = await items.json();
    dispatch(setItems(itemsJson.data));
}

useEffect(() => {
    getItem();
    getItems();
}, [itemId]) // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

return <Box width="80%" m="80px auto">
    <Box display="flex" flexWrap="wrap" columnGap="40px">
        {/* IMAGES */}
        <Box flex="1 1 40%" mb="40px">
            <img 
                alt={item?.name}
                width="100%"
                height="100%"
                src={`http://localhost:1337${item?.attributes?.image?.data?.attributes?.formats?.medium?.url}`}
                style={{ objectFit: "contain" }}
            />
        </Box>

        {/* ACTIONS */}
        <Box flex="1 1 50%" mb="40px">
            <Box display="flex" justifyContent="space-between">
                <Box>Home/Item</Box>
                <Box>Prev Next</Box>
            </Box>

            <Box m="65px 0 25px 0">
                <Typography variant="h3">{item?.attributes?.name}</Typography>
                <Typography>{item?.attributes?.price}</Typography>
                <Typography sx={{ mt: "20px" }}>
                    {item?.attributes?.longDescription}
                </Typography>
            </Box>

            {/* COUNT & BUTTON */}
            <Box display="flex" alignItems="center" minHeight="50px">
                <Box 
                    display="flex" 
                    alignItems="center" 
                    border={`1.5px solid ${shades.neutral[300]}`}
                    mr="20px"
                    padding="2px 5px"
                >
                    <IconButton
                        onClick={() => 
                            setCount(Math.max(count -1, 1))
                        }
                    >
                        <RemoveIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                    <Typography sx={{ p: "0 5px"}}>{count}</Typography>
                    <IconButton
                        onClick={() => 
                            setCount(count + 1)
                        }
                    >
                        <AddIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                </Box>

                <Button 
                    sx={{ 
                        backgroundColor: "#222222",
                        color: "white",
                        borderRadius: 0,
                        minWidth: "150px",
                        padding: "10px 40px"
                    }}
                    onClick={() => dispatch(addToCart({ item: {...item, count}}))} 
                >
                    ADD TO CART
                </Button>
            </Box>

            <Box>
                <Box m="20px 0 5px 0" display="flex">
                    <FavoriteBorderOutlinedIcon />
                    <Typography sx={{ ml: "5px"}}>ADD TO WISHLIST</Typography>
                </Box>
                <Typography>CATEGORIES: {item?.attributes?.category}</Typography>
            </Box>
        </Box>
    </Box>

    {/* INFOFRMATION */}
    <Box m="20px 0">
        <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
            <Tab label="DESCRIPTION" value="description" />
            <Tab label="REVIEWS" value="reviews" />
        </Tabs>
    </Box>
    <Box display="flex" flexWrap="wrap" gap="15px">
        {value === "description" && (
            <div>{item?.attributes?.longDescription}</div>
        )}
        {value === "reviews" && <div>reviews</div>}
    </Box>

    {/* RELATED ITEMS */}
    <Box mt="50px" width="100%">
        <Typography variant="h3" fontWeight="bold">
            Related Products
        </Typography>
        
       {/* This Bottom Box seems to be the reason the browser goes blank */}
        <Box 
            mt="20px"
            display="flex"
            flexWrap="wrap"
            columnGap="1.33%"
            justifyContent="space-between"
        >
            {items.slice(0,4).map((item, i) => (
                <Item key={`${item.name}-${i}`} item={item} />
            ))}
        </Box>
    </Box>
</Box>
}

export default ItemDetails;
```

Comment: show more, please. Where is the ```import``` ?

Comment: Looks like `items` is undefined? Please [edit] the post to include a more complete and comprehensive [mcve] so readers have complete context.

Comment: open the console and see. there should be some info why

Comment: What is the value of `itemsJson`? `setItems` also is a void return, you are dispatching an undefined value with `dispatch(setItems(itemsJson.data));`. What is the goal of this logic?

Comment: The value of  itemsJson is await items.json(); .I'm trying to fetch an item from Strapi. I've removed the dispatch and left setItems(itemsJson.data); but I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: Can you try to log the value of  itemsJson just before storing it in the state? That will help you debug what is inside the variable, maybe the `data` does not contain an array
```const itemsJson = await items.json();
  console.log(itemsJson); // add this
  setItems(itemsJson.data);
```

Comment: The value of `itemsJson` ***is not*** `await items.json()`, the value of `itemsJson` will be whatever the ***resolved*** value from `items.json()` you `await`-ed on. The next line assumes `itemsJson.data` is defined and exists. It seems it is the case that `itemsJson.data` is undefined because this is the only `items` state update I see in the code you've provided and the error is definitely telling you that `items` is undefined.

Comment: Problem solved. I got the source code.  ~ file: ItemDetails.jsx:45 ~ getItems ~ itemsJson: Object
data
: 
(18) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
meta
: 
{pagination: {…}}
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object